# How to correctly parse lambda's whitespace separated log in Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, parsing, aws-lambda, logparser, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

i have this type of log in @message:

`2022-06-16T10:35:12.921Z 8984a0e4-0ff0-4cfd-ac5a-a312ec3f6157 DEBUG successfully retrieved 15758 object`

How can i parse this log to have different columns with: timestamp (2022-06-16T10:35:12.921Z), requestID (8984a0e4-0ff0-4cfd-ac5a-a312ec3f6157), type(DEBUG), message (successfully retrieved 15758 object)?

I've tried with this query but the field type and message are not correctly recognized:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @requestId
| parse @message "* * * *" as timestamp, requestId, type, message
| display @timestamp, @requestId, type, message
```

the result is that timestamp and requestID are correctly identified, while in type there is "15758" instead of DEBUG and in message there is "object"....

how can i modify this query to have the correct output fields?

Comment: Hi Paolo, yes i need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parsing engine for CloudWatch Logs insights supports using regular expressions, so you can use a regex to obtain the desired result:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message /^(?<timestamp>[^\s]+) (?<requestId>[^\s]+) (?<type>[^\s]+) (?<message>.+$)/
| display timestamp, requestId, type, message
```

will result in:

[image]

To see how this regex works in action you can use this [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ou7Xzv/1).

Comment: This failed for me because Lambda logs tabs instead of spaces between fields. This worked: `parse @message /^(?<timestamp>[^\s]+)\t(?<requestId>[^\s]+)\t(?<level>[^\s]+)\t(?<message>.+$)/`

Comment: @kichik well yes, this answer was for space separated fields